# Why is the Normalized Device Coordinate system left-handed?

Tags: opengl

At first I wondered why NDC ranges from -1 to 1, rather than from 0 to 1. I figured maybe having the origin at the center is useful for something.

But why is it using a left-handed coordinate system?

Could it be just so that the Z-value is higher for objects farther away? That would be a good enough reason for me.

Comment: I don't understand how a centered origin means that it is "left handed"...

Comment: I never implied that. See here: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html Rephrased my question.

Comment: Why would a right-handed system be better?

Comment: @cbamber85 It would then be consistent with everything else. And please justify downvotes, whoever it was...

Comment: I see.  I was honestly asking as I didn't understand the distinction.

Comment: Like any three dimensional coordinate system that isn't used by trolls to confuse other people. I'm kidding of course but I'm just looking for a reason why a left handed coordinate system for NDC is justified. Because if there is no justification, I'm sure they would have made it right-handed just like everything else.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the "everything else", the only framework/API I can think that has a _fixed_ right-handed coordinate system is Direct3D...  Otherwise they are mathematically and computationally equivalent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But why is it using a left-handed coordinate system?

Let's add "by default" to that question. Because all that's needed to change it is `glDepthRange(1.0f, 0.0f);` and now you're right-handed. And yes, that is perfectly legal GL syntax; there has never been a restriction that the range near z is less than the range far z.

Why is it left-handed by default? Maybe someone on the ARB liked it that way. Maybe someone on the ARB liked increasing depth range instead of decreasing, and the lower-left corner orientation made that necessary. Maybe because the progenitor of OpenGL, IRIX GL, did it this way and the ARB didn't see any need to change it.

The reason for this is immaterial; handedness is purely a notational convenience. In some places, right-handed makes sense. In others, left-handed makes sense. And since it is trivially changed, just use what works for you.

> It would then be consistent with everything else.

Consistent with *what* everything else? All of the fixed-function stuff that's been removed?

The viewport transform is all done by OpenGL internally, where nobody can get at it. You don't even provide a matrix; you just provide a viewport and depth range. So from the perspective of someone using fixed-function GL, everything really is right-handed.

The only time the handedness even comes up is when dealing with vertex shaders directly, where you have to know what the handedness of the clip-space is. And in that case, the change in handedness is a simple function of the perspective projection negating the Z. Or, if you like left-handed coordinates, the perspective projection *not* negating the Z. Or again, just reverse the `glDepthRange` and now you're right-handed.

Answer (score 8):

> But why is it using a left-handed coordinate system?

So that increasing distances from the projection plane in view direction map to increasing values of the depth buffer.

> Could it be just so that the Z-value is higher for objects farther away? That would be a good enough reason for me.

Well, that's exactly why it is that way.

Answer (score 0):

Guess the change in handedness is owned to how graphics cards interpret z values. Greater z value -> greater depth. The implied change of handedness can be performed by the projection matrix without additional costs. Changing it later would add an additional computation step.