# Ortho and Persp are reversing Z depth sign?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glm-math

NDC coordinates for OpenGL form a cube, who's `-Z` side presses against the screen while it's `+Z` side is farthest away.

When I use...

```
// ortho arguments are: left, right,  bottom, top,  near, far
pos = pos * glm::ortho<float>(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

...the `z` component of `pos` is reflected; -1 becomes 1, 10 becomes -10, etc.

glm::persp does a similar thing and it's kind of a weird?  If a position has a `z` equal to `near`, I would expect it to rest on the screen facing plane of the NDC cube, but instead it's sign is flipped arbitrarily; it doesn't even land on the farthest facing side.

Why is this?

Comment: Song Ho Ahn made a nice tutorial about transformations: [OpenGL Projection Matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) which I periodically re-visit to clear up my mind. All the transformations make me dizzy sometimes. But this time I'm quite sure as I recently did a toy project where I made everything "manually": [NoGL3dDemo](https://github.com/scheff173/NoGL3dDemo).

Comment: back in the days of GL 1.0 we used `gluPerspective` for perspective matrix and it inverts Z axis. GLM math was created a long time after and my guess is they wanted to maintain compatibility. It really does not matter if you are viewing in `+Z` or `-Z` direction as the depth values in NDC are still `[-1,+1]` you just set front face and depth test function accordingly ... so if you want you just invert the Z axis back by scaling ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NDC coordinates for OpenGL form a cube, who's -Z side presses against the screen while it's +Z side is farthest away.

I had a look into Song Ho Ahns tutorial about OpenGL transformations to be sure not to tell something silly.

[**Perspective Projection**](https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#perspective)

> In perspective projection, a 3D point in a truncated pyramid frustum (eye coordinates) is mapped to a cube (NDC); the range of x-coordinate from [l, r] to [-1, 1], the y-coordinate from [b, t] to [-1, 1] and the z-coordinate from [-n, -f] to [-1, 1].
>
> Note that the eye coordinates are defined in the right-handed coordinate system, but **NDC uses the left-handed coordinate system**. That is, the camera at the origin is looking along -Z axis in eye space, but it is looking along +Z axis in NDC.

(Emphasizing is mine.)

He provides the following nice illustration for this:

[image: Perspective Frustum and Normalized Device Coordinates (NDC)]

So, I came to the conclusion that

```
glm::ortho<float>(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

shouldn't produce an identity matrix but instead one where z axis is mirrored, e.g. something like

```
|  1  0  0  0 |
|  0  1  0  0 |
|  0  0 -1  0 |
|  0  0  0  1 |
```

As I have no `glm` at hand, I took the relevant code lines from the source code on github ([**glm**](https://github.com/g-truc/glm)). Digging a while in the source code, I finally found the implementation of `glm::ortho()` in [`orthoLH_ZO()`](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/ext/matrix_clip_space.inl):

```
template<typename T>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoLH_ZO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
{
    mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(1);
    Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
    Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
    Result[2][2] = static_cast<T>(1) / (zFar - zNear);
    Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
    Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    Result[3][2] = - zNear / (zFar - zNear);
    return Result;
}
```

I transformed this code a bit to make the following sample:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

struct Mat4x4 {
  double values[4][4];
  Mat4x4() { }
  Mat4x4(double val)
  {
    values[0][0] = val; values[0][1] = 0.0; values[0][2] = 0.0; values[0][3] = 0.0;
    values[1][0] = 0.0; values[1][1] = val; values[1][2] = 0.0; values[1][3] = 0.0;
    values[2][0] = 0.0; values[2][1] = 0.0; values[2][2] = val; values[2][3] = 0.0;
    values[3][0] = 0.0; values[3][1] = 0.0; values[3][2] = 0.0; values[3][3] = val;
  }
  double* operator[](unsigned i) { return values[i]; }
  const double* operator[](unsigned i) const { return values[i]; }
};

Mat4x4 ortho(
  double left, double right, double bottom, double top, double zNear, double zFar)
{
  Mat4x4 result(1.0);
  result[0][0] = 2.0 / (right - left);
  result[1][1] = 2.0 / (top - bottom);
  result[2][2] = - 1;
  result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
  result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
  return result;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Mat4x4 &mat)
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << std::setw(8) << mat[i][j];
    }
    out << '\n';
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  Mat4x4 matO = ortho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
  std::cout << matO;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and started it provides the following output:

```
   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000
   0.000   0.000  -1.000   0.000
  -0.000  -0.000   0.000   1.000
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4db52497c0151633)

Huh! z is scaled with -1 i.e. z values are mirrored on x-y plane (as expected).

Hence, OP's observation is fully correct and reasonable:

> ...the z component of pos is reflected; -1 becomes 1, 10 becomes -10, etc.

---

The hardest part:

> Why is this?

My personal guess: one of the SGI guru's who invented all this GL stuff did this in her/his wiseness.

Another guess: In eye space, x axis points to right and y axis points up. Translating this into screen coordinates, y axis should point down (as pixels are usually/technically addressed beginning in the upper left corner). So, this introduces another mirrored axis which changes handedness of coordinate system (again).

It's a bit unsatisfying and hence I googled and found this (duplicate?):

[SO: Why is the Normalized Device Coordinate system left-handed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9385520/7478597)