# Use top-left origin in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to set my co-ordinate system such that the y-axis points down the screen.

```
// Determine view-projection matrix
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(
    -3.0f,    // left
    3.0f,     // right
    3.0f,     // bottom
    -3.0f);   // top

// Right handed rule:
// x points right
// y points down
// z points into the screen
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0, 0, -1),    // camera position
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),     // look at
    glm::vec3(0, -1, 0)     // up vector
);

glm::mat4 viewProjMatrix = projection * view;
```

However, when I try to render 2 objects:

```
A at (0, 0)
B at (1, 1)
```

A appears in the centre of the screen, and B appears in the top-right. I would expect it to appear in the bottom-right.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want your top-left to be 0,0 you should pass in `0` as top and left to your ortho matrix.

Comment: Although, I agree with @tkausl - this doesn't explain fully what you get. _B appears in the top-right._ sounds like if you don't apply your projection matrix to rendering of A and B.

Comment: The `glm::lookAt()` makes me suspicious a bit as well. Normally, x points right, y points up, z points _out of_ screen. Remember that the full transformation is model, view, projection (-> projection * view * model * v) i.e. projection is applied after view.

Comment: Sorry, poorly-worded question, I have just corrected it.

Comment: @Scheff I am applying the matrix as follows: `gl_Position = view_proj_matrix * vec4(in_vertex.x, in_vertex.y, 0, 1);`

Comment: In this case, it might be worth to watch the `glm::lookAt()` again. (Sorry, all the transformations make me always a bit dizzy. Impossible for me to get it correct on paper - mostly it's not correct before switching the one or other sign in code. And be careful about handedness. A scaling of (1, -1, 1) can switch from RH to LH and vice versa. Though, not an issue if you render front and back...) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Using the right-hand rule, when x points right and y points up, then z points out of the screen, as you said. But if you rotate these axes such that y points down, then z is pointing into the screen. At least, that was my reasoning.

Comment: So, you turned your view up-side-down (with `glm::lookat()`). This makes bottom top and top bottom. Now, if you mirror projection on horizontal axis (with `glm::ortho()`), bottom becomes top and top becomes bottom. So, top is top again and bottom is bottom again. Could you follow? :-)

Comment: That makes sense: the axes are fundamentally x-right, y-up, z-out, and `glLookAt` only changes the position and orientation of the camera. So, I should use "normal" values for `glLookAt`, and just swap `top` and `bottom` in the call to `glOrtho`? Won't this also flip all my textures upside-down?

Comment: Sorry for delay. (You didn't address me.) _just swap top and bottom in the call to glOrtho_ This seems appropriate to how I understood your question. _Won't this also flip all my textures upside-down?_ Yepp. (The same if you instead only turn your view.) Textures (i.e. texture coordinates) map vertex coordinates to image coordinates (or vice versa). Imagine textures as wall papers. If you turn your head in the room, walls will move relative to your eyes as well as the wall paper patterns.

Comment: Btw. if you just _just swap top and bottom in the call to glOrtho_, the handedness of your outcome changes. This might be relevant if you enabled front- or backface culling. Otherwise, it might be tolerable. I once investigated a bit deeper into projection with `glm::ortho()`: [SO: Ortho and Persp are reversing Z depth sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887566/7478597). Not sure whether it provides added value but you might decide on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

My camera was positioned correctly (in a manner of speaking), but I was flipping the y-axis in the call to `glOrtho`.

## Let's visualize this

Imagine a right-handed co-ordinate system such as OpenGL uses by convention:

- The x-axis points right
- The y-axis points up
- The z-axis points out of the screen

If my objects were positioned in this world and we viewed them from the front, we would see this:

```
    B
A
```

This is the same as what I was seeing, but we *weren't* viewing from the front. As @Scheff pointed out in the comments, my call to `glm::lookat` was flipping my camera upside-down and positioning it "behind" the screen.

Now, if you imagine that you are doing a handstand behind your monitor, A and B would now look like this:

```
∀
```

Wait, but isn't this what I wanted - B in the bottom-right?

Right, but in addition to my camera being positioned strangely, my y-axis was being flipped by the call to `glm::ortho`. Normally the value for `bottom` should be less than the value for `top` (as in [this example](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/FAQ#How_to_render_in_pixel_space)).

Thus producing, once again:

```
    B
A
```

So, one solution would have been to swap the `top` and `bottom` parameters in `glOrtho`:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0, 0, -1),    // camera position
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),     // look at
    glm::vec3(0, -1, 0)     // up vector
);
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(
    -3.0f,      // left
    3.0f,       // right
    -3.0f,      // bottom (less than top -> y-axis is not inverted!)
    3.0f);      // top
```

## How to flip the y-axis "correctly"

The solution above works, but there is a much simpler solution - or at least much simpler to visualize! And that is just to position the camera in front of the scene and flip the y-axis using `glOrtho` (by keeping `bottom` greater than `top`):

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 1),     // camera position
    glm::vec3(0, 0, 0),     // look at
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)      // up vector
);
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(
    -3.0f,      // left
    3.0f,       // right
    3.0f,       // bottom (greater than top -> y-axis is inverted!)
    -3.0f);     // top
```

## Potential problems

### Texture orientation

Flipping the y-axis may result in upside-down textures, which can be fixed by swapping your top and bottom texture co-ordinates.

### Back-face culling

Viewing the scene from a different angle may result in faces being culled, if [face culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) is enabled. This can be fixed by changing the winding order of your vertices, or by changing *which* faces get culled.