# OpenGL depth buffer inverted/flipper over y-axis

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to get the depthmap of a shape using the depth buffer (and ortographic projection), but somehow the y-axis is flipped.

I use an OpenCV Mat to display the depth map.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;
    int screenWidth = 450, screenHeight = 350;

    GLfloat color[] =
    {
        255, 0, 0,
        0, 255, 0,
        0, 0, 255
    };

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -200.0f, -50.0f, -100.0f,
        250.0f, 150.0f, 0.0f,
        100.0f, 300.0f, 0.0f
    };

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create windows
    window = glfwCreateWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    cv::namedWindow("Depthmap", cv::WindowFlags::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-200.0f, 250.0f, -50.0f, 300.0f, 0, 100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    while (true)
    {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix();

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, color);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glPopMatrix();

        //To opencv mat
        cv::Mat depth = cv::Mat_<float>(screenHeight, screenWidth);
        glReadPixels(0, 0, depth.cols, depth.rows, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth.data);
        cv::imshow("Depthmap", depth);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:
[image: Inverted y-axis on depthmap]

The actual depth seems to be correct (the red point is 1.0 and the green and blue points are 0.0) but the y-axis is inverted. Why is this and how can I fix it properly?

Comment: opencv and opengl use different coordinate systems (for multiple reasons).

Comment: so for your problem: OpenCV has the image origin in the top-left, while openGL afaik has the origin in the bottom-left and both correspond to the individual represenation of 3D space, where openCV has the y axis "downwards".

Comment: Ah, it's that simple. I didn't think about the possibility that it was in the opencv part. Thnx!

Comment: FYI: [SO: Ortho and Persp are reversing Z depth sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887566/7478597)